# Elastic Search query: filter aggregation by number range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query like

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "created_date":{
                     "gte":1801301,
                     "lte":1807061
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "rating":{
         "filters":{
            "filters":{
               "neutral":{
                  "match":{
                     "rating":0
                  }
               },
               "positive":{
                  "match":{
                     "rating":1
                  }
               },
               "negative":{
                  "match":{
                     "rating":2
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size":0

}
```

The query filters documents by created_date. I use date range that covers two date ranges: current and previous. Like data for this month and previous month. This is needed in other calculations(original query is much bigger).

This query works, but it calculates the rating for current and previous date ranges. I need to calculate rating  in shorter date range: created_date: 1804181-1807061.

Is there a way how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
{
    "range: {
        "created_date": {
            "gte":"now-10d/d",
            "lte":"now/d"
        }
    }
}
```